# Flutter UI is broken first screen

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, skia

I have this UI issue when opening the build (on a device) made from a flutter project and I don't event know where to begin.

[image]

I observe this issue every time I reopen the app on the screen that starts.
If a UI render comes along (push/flip to landscape-portrait/popup), 
it comes back to normal.

```
> flutter doctor 
> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor
> -v): [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.5.4-hotfix.2, on Mac OS X 10.14.4 18E226, locale en-RO)   [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android
> devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3) [✓] iOS toolchain - develop for
> iOS devices (Xcode 10.2) [✓] Android Studio (version 3.3) [✓] VS Code
> (version 1.33.1) [✓] Connected device (1 available)
> 
> • No issues found!
```

(I am not doing anything fancy in the code... just a normal Login screen)

Comment: Please send code

Comment: The code should not be relevant as I get this for more than one apps. It seems like a framework behaviour that I am not aware.

Comment: Any update on this? Even I faced the same issue just now. Appeared out of nowhere

Comment: @SiddharthPatankar please check as I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered on git [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32675).

This is a bug in flutter v1.2 (and previous as I observed on previous builds) and to resolve this you need to **update to flutter v1.5**